Planet where time slowed/stands still and fight ants on ledge
I saw this movie (from the 50s?) on TV as a child in later 60's. I recall it being b/w. I recall somewhat clearly a number of 'explorers' on a distant planet moving up a narrowish path/ledge along the side of a mountain.  Heading to a City/Building they had seen at the top.  
Key point was them encountering some 'giant ants' on the path and having to get [fight?] past them. The ants were possibly claymation style but in b/w they were very surreal looking and worked well to my young mind.
What is really tugging at me to find this movie is something about the city they reach.  I believe the ants may have been workers for some other race. And most importantly something about time - either distorted or it is slowed or ends up standing still.
I have searched all the lists and researched those I thought may be close.  
What is worse is that I swear I saw it as part of a collection DVD set and the name was so obvious that I didn't worry about finding later!  Yeah Right!

It sounds familiar to me, but what I'm thinking of has skeletons instead of ants. Is it possible that you're not confusing those?

Might have been skeletons in there.

Could it have been The First Men in the Moon? It's in color, but memories can be deceiving :)

Yes!  tremendous!

And P.S. how did you remember it?

Could it have been the 1964 version of First Men in the Moon?
Here are some images to jog your memory - they feature 'ant-like' aliens (Selanites) battling explorers on a narrow cliff path on a far off planet (the moon, almost a planet ;)) and there is a skeleton in the mix.




Tremendous!  How could I have not found this.  Thank you so much!   Though not quite ants, those creatures certainly have that odd movement claymation like that stayed with me as a kid.  The trailer shows the one thing I could not describe which was the 'leader' whom I simply recalled being in some way odd or disturbing - and now I remember.  And although the trailer doesn't seem to show anything about time dilation or standing still, it may have been a combination of the 'insectoid' movements and the ending I read about with the city crumbling.  I may not have understood the flashback nature.

You're welcome :)
The stop-motion was by the great Ray Harryhausen - a classic film!
